# How to efficiently solve a series of similar matrix equations using the LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

This is the problem I'm dealing with:

Let $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ be column vectors of length $n$. Consider the system
$$ (A - \sigma_jI)x_j = b_j, \quad (j=1,\dots,n).$$
Show this can be solved in $2n^3$ flops neglecting terms of order $n^2$ and lower.

My progress: Since LU decomposition takes $2n^3/3$ flops in general, we can't solve the system $n$ times. My first idea is to somehow link the LU decomposition of $A$ with $A - \sigma_jI$, which we can do with the relationship
$$ LU - \sigma_j I = L_jU_j$$
If we define $L_jU_j$ as the LU decomposition of $A - \sigma_j I$. This is where I'm stuck. The expressions we have are the product of $L$ and $U$, which makes it difficult to derive an expression for either of the two. If we have $L,U$ as given, how can we find $L_jU_j$ without doing another decomposition?

Comment: Is anything known about $A$? Is it just real non-symmetric?

Comment: Hijacking this question to ask my own (sirry it has abounty so many people view it! :o) ). I think I have a millenium prize question, how do I submit to Harvard? Question is secret until copyright. nuh uh uh. Thanks for the help :o)

Answer (score 2):

If you find an orthogonal similarity transformation $A=QTQ^t$, then the problem woul become
$$ Q(T+\sigma_j)Q^tx_j = b_j, $$
which involves solving equations with the matrix $T+\sigma_j$.

If $T$ comes from the [Schur decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchurDecomposition.html), then it is upper-triangular (although complex), and solving $(T+\sigma_j)y_j=c_j$ can be done with back-substitution.

You can also compute a $T$ with the real Schur decomposition, which gives a real quasi-triangular matrix $T$: $T$ is zero below the first subdiagonal, and its diagonal consists of $1\times1$ and $2\times 2$ blocks. The $1\times1$ blocks correspond to real eigenvalues, and the $2\times 2$ blocks correspond to the complex eigenvalues. However, computing the real Schur decomposition is a lot more expensive than $2n^3$, although it is still $O(n^3)$. For example, [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1RealSchur.html) gives complexity of $25n^3$.

Also note that the orthogonal matrix $Q$ should be kept in a form that allows you to compute $Qx$ and $Q^tx$ efficiently; forming it explicitly is not really necessary. For example, if $Q$ is a product of Householder reflections, you can keep a list of individual reflections.

None of this gives $2n^3$ flops, although it is $O(n^3)$. In fact, at least in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.386.3031) and [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=639087), the authors are unaware of any especially efficient technique for solving shifted systems of linear equations of the kind you have here, and discuss Krylov-type methods. Krylov-type methods can take advantage of the fact that the basis of the Krylov space is invariant under shifts.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the decomposition $LU$ has nothing to do. You must diagonalize $A$ or, at least, triangularize $A$ with an orthonormal change of basis. This can be done in $O(n^3)$. The sequel is easy and can be done in $n$ calculations in $O(n^2)$, that is, in $O(n^3)$ again.

Clearly, you work in $\mathbb{C}$ using numerical approximations.

EDIT: @ Kirill , a complexity $\sim 2n^3$ seems to me hopeless. Indeed, the calculation of the eigenvalues of a random $n\times n$ matrix is (I think) at least $\sim 5n^3$. With Matlab on a PC, we obtain the eigenvalues of a $1000\times 1000$ random matrix in 5". cf. fanfan's post in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713878/how-expensive-is-it-to-compute-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix

It remains to compare with the duration of the calculation of $A^{-1}$ which is $\sim n^3$.

Comment: The question specifically says $2n^3$ flops, not $O(n^3)$ flops. I'm not quite sure how one would diagonalize a matrix in $2n^3$ flops. Can you be more specific?

Comment: [[I don't get notifications for mentions in questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019)] "complexity ∼2n3 seems to me hopeless" Yes, that's what I thought. The result doesn't *have* to be triangular, it can be the real Schur decomposition, for example, that would still work.